# Prometheus won't connect to Synapse metrics

Tags: matrix, prometheus, matrix-synapse

I tried to follow this guide to configure prometheus with synapse metrics: https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse/blob/master/docs/metrics-howto.md

I'm having difficulties though. Here's how i set it up:

$ sudo ufw allow 9090

$ sudo nano /etc/matrix-synapse/homeserver.yaml

```
# in listeners: list
  - type: metrics
    port: 9000
    bind_addresses:
      - '0.0.0.0'

## Metrics ###

# Enable collection and rendering of performance metrics
#
enable_metrics: true
```

Restarted Synapse, installed Docker.

Create '/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml' edit it like so:

$ sudo nano /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets:
      # - alertmanager:9093

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  - job_name: "synapse"
    metrics_path: "/_synapse/metrics"
    scheme: "https"
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:9000"]
```

Attempt to start Prometheus:

$ docker run -p 9090:9090 -v /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --name prometheus prom/prometheus

```
level=info ts=2020-05-06T03:42:50.799Z caller=main.go:298 msg="no time or size retention was set so using the default time retention" duration=15d
level=info ts=2020-05-06T03:42:50.799Z caller=main.go:333 msg="Starting Prometheus" version="(version=2.17.2, branch=HEAD, revision=18254838fbe25dcc732c950ae05f78ed4db1292c)"
level=info ts=2020-05-06T03:42:50.799Z caller=main.go:334 build_context="(go=go1.13.10, user=root@9cb154c268a2, date=20200420-08:27:08)"
level=info ts=2020-05-06T03:42:50.800Z caller=main.go:335 host_details="(Linux 4.19.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.98-1+deb10u1 (2020-04-27) x86_64 0cf4549b1dcd (none))"
level=info ts=2020-05-06T03:42:50.800Z caller=main.go:336 fd_limits="(soft=1048576, hard=1048576)"
level=info ts=2020-05-06T03:42:50.800Z caller=main.go:337 vm_limits="(soft=unlimited, hard=unlimited)"
level=info ts=2020-05-06T03:42:50.802Z caller=main.go:667 msg="Starting TSDB ..."
level=info ts=2020-05-06T03:42:50.802Z caller=web.go:515 component=web msg="Start listening for connections" address=0.0.0.0:9090
level=info ts=2020-05-06T03:42:50.806Z caller=head.go:575 component=tsdb msg="replaying WAL, this may take awhile"
level=info ts=2020-05-06T03:42:50.806Z caller=head.go:624 component=tsdb msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=0 maxSegment=0
level=info ts=2020-05-06T03:42:50.807Z caller=head.go:627 component=tsdb msg="WAL replay completed" duration=403.999µs
level=info ts=2020-05-06T03:42:50.808Z caller=main.go:683 fs_type=9123683e
level=info ts=2020-05-06T03:42:50.808Z caller=main.go:684 msg="TSDB started"
level=info ts=2020-05-06T03:42:50.808Z caller=main.go:788 msg="Loading configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
level=info ts=2020-05-06T03:42:50.809Z caller=main.go:816 msg="Completed loading of configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
level=info ts=2020-05-06T03:42:50.810Z caller=main.go:635 msg="Server is ready to receive web requests."
```

But it just hangs taking the console away from me. :P I can detach it while running it at least.

I could see Prometheus at 192.168.1.171:9090 but it was not recording/showing synapse metrics. :/

Downloaded synapse-v2.rules from here: https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse/tree/master/contrib/prometheus

Edit: Thanks i edited out the https section, and pointed it to the new rules file, here is my prometheus.yml:

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets:
      # - alertmanager:9093

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  - "/etc/prometheus/synapse-v2.rules"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  - job_name: "synapse"
    metrics_path: "/_synapse/metrics"
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:9000"]
```

Then i restarted the Prometheus docker but it still isn't presenting the synapse metrics in the web dropdown.

[There are prometheus statistics but no synapse ones.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhLFf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried downloading the compiled package and running that instead, worked well.

Answer (score 0):

> `scheme: "https"`

Synapse's metrics listener doesn't use tls. Remove this.

Comment: thanks i changed the Prometheus config as you can see above but it still doesn't recognize Synapse statistics :S

Answer (score 0):

> ```yaml
> static_configs:
>   - targets: ["localhost:9000"]
> ```
>
> $ **docker run** -p 9090:9090 -v /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --name prometheus prom/prometheus

`localhost` here is the Docker container's `localhost`. Only things within the Docker container will be reachable in there.

Comment: I published the 9000 port as well like so:
"$ docker run -p 9090:9090 -p 9000:9000 -v /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --name prometheus prom/prometheus &"

But the docker spat this error at me:

"$ docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint prometheus (e52df6b1358a0aaf710e046163efc774f52d08e0e8486840a1a294b3d3b4badf): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:9000: bind: address already in use.
ERRO[0019] error waiting for container: context canceled"